# javascript if condition behavior

Tags: javascript

I have this strange behavior I can't understand, can any one explain?

I'm trying to scrape some info from a web page, using Nightmare.js.
After it comes to picking data from DOM I use some validation to ensure that particular element exists on page, like this

PROJECT CODE: WORKING WITH THIRD SNIPPET

```
var data = yield nightmare.evaluate(() => {
    var list = document.querySelector('#offers_container');
    var sorted = list.getElementsByClassName('col-third');
    var arr = [];
    //var obj = {};


    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        var text = ''; // working
        var price_new = '';
        var price_old = '';
        var image_link = '';
        var discount_percent = '';
        var extras = [];

        // Grabing elements
        /*  SOMETIMES I GOT ERROR Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
        if(sorted[i].querySelector('.title')){
            text = sorted[i].querySelector('.title').innerHTML;
        } else {
            text = '';
        }
        */
        // THIRD SNIPPET EXAMPLE WORKING
        text = sorted[i].querySelector('.title')? sorted[i].querySelector('.title').innerHTML : '';
        price_new = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value')? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value').innerHTML + '.' + sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.cents').innerHTML  : '';
        price_old = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value')? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value').innerHTML : '';
        image_link = sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img')? sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img').getAttribute('src') : '';
        discount_percent = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value')? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value').innerHTML : '';

        // Check's extras
        var check_extras = sorted[i].querySelector('div.tags.tags_primary');
        if(check_extras){
            var divs = check_extras.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for(var e = 0; e < divs.length; e++){
                var data_alt = divs[e].getAttribute('data-alt');
                extras.push(data_alt);
            }
        }

        arr.push(
            {
                text: text,
                price_new: price_new,
                price_old: price_old,
                discount_percent: discount_percent,
                image_link: image_link,
                extras: extras
            });
    }



    return arr;

});
```

**NOT WORKS**
sometimes it passing condition, I think it returns object and it pass, and then it try to take innerHTML it throws error, that this element not exist

```
if(document.querySelector('some selector')){
  var element_data = document.querySelector('some selector').innerHTML;
}
```

So this line of code sometimes works and sometimes not, I read about that the return from DOM is Object, so from other examples I found people are writing like this:

**NOT WORKS**

```
if(typeof document.querySelector('some selector') == 'undefined' || !document.querySelector('some selector')){
  console.log('No element');
} else { 
  var element_data = document.querySelector('some selector').innerHTML;
}
```

And this line also not works as expected.

But then I use this line of code, it works very well:
**WORKS**

```
var element_data = document.querySelector('some selector') ? document.querySelector('some selector').innerHTML : 'no data';
```

So it's same `if` check condition, I want to understand what stands behind?

How should the code look like if I write it in old fashion way?

FULL WORKING CODE CHECK

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');

vo(run)(function (err, res) {
if (err) console.log(err);

console.dir(res.data);

});


function* run() {
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
var su = {};
var buttonExists = true;
var buttonVisible = true;
yield nightmare.goto('https://www.maxima.lt/akcijos').wait('body');


while (buttonVisible) {
    console.log('Click');
    yield nightmare.click('body > div.wrapper.over.offers.cl > div.wrapper_buttons.centered > a');
    console.log('waiting 4.5 s');
    yield nightmare.wait(4500);
    buttonVisible = yield nightmare.visible('body > div.wrapper.over.offers.cl > div.wrapper_buttons.centered > a');
    console.log('Is button visible? ' + buttonVisible);
}

//
yield nightmare.wait(4500);




var data = yield nightmare.evaluate(() => {

    var list = document.querySelector('#offers_container');
    var sorted = list.getElementsByClassName('col-third');
    var arr = [];
    var obj = {};


    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        var text = '';
        var price_new = '';
        var price_old = '';
        var image_link = '';
        var discount_percent = '';
        var extras = [];

        // THIRD CONDITION CHECK EXAMPLE
        text = sorted[i].querySelector('.title') ? sorted[i].querySelector('.title').innerHTML : '';
        price_new = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value') ? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value').innerHTML + '.' + sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.cents').innerHTML : '';
        price_old = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value') ? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value').innerHTML : '';
        image_link = sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img') ? 'https://www.maxima.lt' + sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img').getAttribute('src') : '';
        discount_percent = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value') ? sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value').innerHTML : '';


        // FIRST CONDITION CHECK EXAMPLE
        if (sorted[i].querySelector('.title')) {
            text = sorted[i].querySelector('.title').innerHTML;
        } else {
            text = '';
        }
        if (sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value')) {
            price_new = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.value').innerHTML + '.' + sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t1 > span.cents').innerHTML;
        } else {
            price_new = '';
        }
        if (sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value')) {
            price_old = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.price > div.t2 > span.value').innerHTML;
        } else {
            price_old = '';
        }
        if (sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img')) {
            image_link = sorted[i].querySelector('div.img > img').getAttribute('src');
        } else {
            image_link = '';
        }
        if (sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value')) {
            discount_percent = sorted[i].querySelector('div.discount.percents > span.value').innerHTML;
        } else {
            discount_percent = ''
        }


        // Check's extras
        var check_extras = sorted[i].querySelector('div.tags.tags_primary');
        if (check_extras) {
            var divs = check_extras.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for (var e = 0; e < divs.length; e++) {
                var data_alt = divs[e].getAttribute('data-alt');
                extras.push(data_alt);
            }
        }

        arr.push(
            {
                text: text,
                price_new: price_new,
                price_old: price_old,
                discount_percent: discount_percent,
                image_link: image_link,
                extras: extras
            });
    }



    return arr;

});

su['data'] = data;

//yield nightmare.end();

return su;
}
```

Comment: _“I want to understand what stands behind ? 'question mark'”_ - well then do some absolute basic research ... https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+question+mark

Comment: Yean I got it, a question mark is a common syntax in javascript, is an inline condition where before ? you have the condition, and after it you specify both values for when the condition is true or false respectively

Comment: Some of u are so much don't like green guys, I want to understand what possible conditions are checked, like typeof, != null, lenght, keys maybe others

Comment: @VaidasZonys There's no difference between the conditions of the first and the third snippet. If the first snippet fails, it is due to your testing methods, not any JS "peculiarity".

Comment: For a more specific answer, please define works / not works.

Comment: @Teemu, for me it was something very strange, the I wrote my script all conditions was checked like in first snippet, but then I start testing on real data, there elements was changing due to live web page it's start failing, and then i wrote like in third snippet, it never fail's, so that's why i wrote there, thought maybe there is some sugar behind ? behavior

Comment: There's no sugar, the conditions behave exactly the same way. Your testing method for the first snippet needs to be adjusted, if it fails. You still need to define, what means "working" and "not working", since all the snippets are doing a different task.

Comment: Please show the use-case of the snippet 1. As stated many times, there's no difference between the conditions, it has to be something else in your code.

Comment: @Teemu I updated the code you can see it there its commented

Comment: Yep, now we have a decent question. Unfortunately I have no clue what is going on. If the code in the post is your real code, it never should throw such an error.

Comment: I don't know, indeed it never should throw that error

Comment: Yep, I checked it again, and for real it works, I feel so stupid it was my mistake, just don't know where, I will post all code, and thank you all for your time :)

Comment: Because `!!null === false` it should never enter inside the `true` statement, are you sure you were not using `.innerHTML` property outside some validation?

Comment: @Daniel yes its very possible I did, just without old code can't remember exactly were it could be. tnx